# Generic method with variable type parameter

Tags: c#

I have a simple generic method:

```
public T Show<T>() where T : Form
{
                //
}
```

The call works:
var form = Controller.Show();

But now I want to set either one form class or the other form class as type parameter depending on a variable:

```
Type t = isTestBig ? TestForm1 : TestForm2;
var form = Controller.Show<t>();
```

This does not work.
What do I need to change to make this work?
Thanks.

Comment: What type would `form` be? Should it be `Form` or one of the subclasses?

Comment: It is a Form and not a subclass

Comment: Then you can simply do `Form form = isTestBig ? Controller.Show<TestForm1>() : Controller.Show<TestForm2>();`.